# How to find version of libraries installed for requirements.txt that don't show in pip or conda list?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, shared-libraries, conda, python-3.7

I am trying to get the requirements for my code, but the requirement.txt file exported only contains 4 of the 9 libraries I'm using. I'm wondering if python comes with preloaded libraries when installed? The libraries I'm using are `requests`, `json`, `datetime`, `calendar`, `pandas`, `os`, `openpyxl`, `re`, and `click`. The only versions I was able to get were the versions for `click`,`openpyxl`,`pandas`,`requests`. How to do I get the versions for `json`, `datetime`,`calender`,`os`,and `re`?

I have tried doing a `pip list` and `conda list` but both didn't show the versions for `json`, `datetime`,`calender`,`os`,and `re`.

I am using python 3.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json`, `datetime`,`calender`,`os`,and `re` are all part of the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) and are installed by default.